# Filter through a CSV file to find names that the user types in C

Tags: c, string, csv, pointers

I have a big CSV file, with multiple columns, and I need to write a function that checks each line to see if the name the user types matches the information that is placed on the 2nd column. If it does match, increase the counter (called dupe) and store the information (although haven't gotten to that part yet since I cant make everything else work). Here is my code:

```
char buffer;
fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE, fp);
char* token = strtok(buffer, ";");

while (token !=NULL){
 token = strtok (NULL, ";");
 while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE, fp) != NULL){
    
    token = strtok(buffer, ";");
    strcpy(bufferCode,token);


     token = strtok(NULL, ";");
     strcpy(bufferName,token);


      if(bufferName == name){          <--------- name is the parameter of the function
        dupe++;
      }
  }
```

I've tried different ways and I've looked for ways of fixing the problems I've found but to no avail. Using strtok is the only way I've found of filtering through the CSV and get the information out of it, and at this point I'm out of ideas/don't fully understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Use [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare strings.

Comment: My recommendation is that you find a library to handle all your CSV needs. It might seem as a simple format, but there are corner cases that are very hard to handle.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude agreed, if you google "C library to handle CSV files" you immediately get details of libcsv in github.  The second hit is to 4 previous questions in this site (stackoverflow) which seem to ask very similar questions.

Comment: You can't read a line of text into the single character `char buffer;` and indeed it's unclear what the first six lines are for.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: OP’s problem is not to search through a CSV file. OP’s problem is “…  I need to write a function that…” This is typical of student assignments: The assignment is for the student to write a function. Using a library would not satisfy that purpose and would result in a bad grade or worse.

Comment: The first line should be `char buffer[MAX_LINE];`. Perhaps that was a typo while posting, if so you should always use copy/paste to give the exact code.